# How to expand javascript arithmetic operators

Tags: javascript

Is there some way to expand js arithmetic operators?
For example, like in ruby:

"string" * 2 = "stringstring"

Comment: Unfortunately no. Javascript doesn't support operator overloading.

Comment: why not just make a function concat("string",2) ?

Comment: @Banana: Or even better: `repeat("string", 2)`